# AWS Lambda running Selenium with Docker Image from Macbook M2 Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-chrome, aws-lambda, selenium-chromedriver, arm64

I am running Selenium in AWS Lambda using Docker Image built from here- [Github link](https://github.com/umihico/docker-selenium-lambda/tree/main), with below Docker Code to Install Chrome & ChromeDriver-

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python@sha256:c80401611e707039b37b5cd24b21f01bbcfa2583030123aee375cbcfa5becd5d as build
RUN yum install -y unzip && \
    curl -Lo "/tmp/chromedriver.zip" "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/114.0.5735.90/chromedriver_linux64.zip" && \
    curl -Lo "/tmp/chrome-linux.zip" "https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Linux_x64%2F1135561%2Fchrome-linux.zip?alt=media" && \
    unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip -d /opt/ && \
    unzip /tmp/chrome-linux.zip -d /opt/

...
...
COPY --from=build /opt/chrome-linux /opt/chrome
COPY --from=build /opt/chromedriver /opt/
...
```

If I build Docker Image in Windows, and deploy in AWS Lambda with **x86_x64** architecture, it runs fine.

But if I build it in Macbook with M2 chip, and deploy in **ARM64** architecture, its giving below error with Chrome -

```
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 18, in lambda_handler
driver = web_utils.get_web_driver()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/var/task/common_utils/web_utils.py", line 37, in get_web_driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 84, in __init__
super().__init__(
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 101, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 96, in start
self._start_process(self._path)
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 197, in _start_process
self.process = subprocess.Popen(
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
File "/var/lang/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 1950, in _execute_child
raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/opt/chromedriver'
Error: Exception occurred: [Errno 8] Exec format error: '/opt/chromedriver'
```

As per other StackOverflow questions, it seems like this error ([Errno 8] Exec format error) is due to incorrect Chrome. However unable to understand - in the same AWS Lambda environment how it differs for Windows and Apple M2 chip build docker Image.

Comment: Does the Docker image support `arm64` architecture?

Comment: Yes. It should. AWS Lambda has option to select Amd64.

Comment: AWS Lambda does. But does your image support `arm64`?